# Excel date Format issue - String

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have date format in the following manner in the excel which is in string format:

```
Apr 1, 2016 12:37:06 PM  
Apr 2, 2016 12:00:00 AM  
Apr 1, 2016 9:50:22 AM  
Apr 1, 2016 12:09:38 PM  
Apr 1, 2016 6:53:03 PM  
Apr 1, 2016 1:02:10 PM
```

I have tried converting it from general to date however excel still does not recognize it as date format. Need your advise as what can I try more to solve this.

Thanks in adavance !!

Comment: Does it have to be a formula and how comfortable are you with macros?

Comment: I want it to be in date format. Not well versed with macros

Comment: Assuming your data starts in A1, if you did =isstring(A1) in an empty cell its returning "TRUE"?  Aslo if you enter 2016/03/23 into a cell and set the properties to short date, what order do you see your date in?  YY/MM/DD, MM/DD/YY etc?

Comment: Do you need this all in one column, or do you want the dates in one column and the time in another beside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options for you:

### Option 1

*Text to Columns built in excel feature*

[image: Text to Columns]

Select all Dates for starters.  They need to be in one column.  On the Data ribbon, select Text to Columns.  Light green back ground in the image above.

On the ensuing window that pops up select Fixed Width.  Then select Next.

[image: Fixed Width]

Adjust the columns so you get either a single column or the date in one column with the time in the other. Then select NEXT.

[image: Column adjustment]

In the bottom preview window select the first column.  Then up top select the Date radio button and from the pull down select MDY format.  when ready click on FINISH button

[image: Format Column]

### Option 2

*Formulas*

Ripping out the text from the string and rebuilding the date using some ugly long formulas.  So we are going to do this in parts so you can see how the big ugly gets made.  When we are done we will copy the smaller formulas into one formula which will be big ugly and hard to read.

One of the annoying thing is you have the month as an abbreviation.  Somewhere off to the side you will need to build a table and put all the abbreviations in one column and the corresponding month number in the column to the right.  There may be other ways to do this but this is what I am going with for now.

```
(AA) | (AB)
Jan  | 1
Feb  | 2
Mar  | 3
Apr  | 4 
May  | 5
Jun  | 6
Jul  | 7
Aug  | 8
Sep  | 9
Oct  | 10
Nov  | 11
Dec  | 12
```

So we can either work from biggest (Year) to smallest (seconds) or from left to right.  lets tackle this starting from the left.

First thing first we need to pull the month out.  Thankfully its on the LEFT side and we know its only 3 characters long.  So we can go straight to the excel formula and hard code this in.  And alternative approach would be to find the space.  So first formula to find month is

```
=Left(A1,3)
```

Since we are going to need to know the number of that month we can convert it with a VLOOKUP function (INDEX/MATCH is another option).  Lets put this in column F for now.

```
=VLOOKUP(Left(A1,3),$AA$1:$AB$12,2,0)
```

That should return the number 3 for us.  you will have to adjust the AA1:AB12 to suit where you put the table.

Next we are going to pull the day.  We know its 1 or two characters to the left of the first comma.  We will use the FIND to determine where that is since it is not in a fixed position.

```
=FIND(",",A1)
```

So we know the date will start either 1 or 2 characters to the left.  No harm in taking two as it will be a space or a number.  So now lets use that knowledge with the MID formula and place the following in column G for now:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)-2,2)
```

the -- changed the text to a number  (they are not actually needed in this case).  So the next one is a little trickier but still doable.  We need to find the Year.  wouldn't you know it, its a fixed 4 characters long and starts just after that same first coma.  So lets reuse our previous formula but tweak it a little and put the following in column H for now:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,4)
```

Well now that we have our Month, Day and Year as numbers we can build our date using the DATE formula which we can drop in say column I:

```
=DATE(H1,F1,G1)
```

now if you thing you are ready to get started on the big an ugly we can substitute each of our previous equation into our date equation so its all done in one cell.  That big formula is going to look as follows:

```
=DATE(MID($A1,FIND(",",$A1)+2,4),VLOOKUP(LEFT($A1,3),$AA$1:$AB$12,2,0),MID($A1,FIND(",",$A1)-2,2))
```

Now when I say all in one cell, I should add the caveat that you do need that helper information of the list of months...though there is a way around that too.  So that takes care of the date process.  now to do the time is very very similar.

We have two options  The first option may not work for you since the datevalue formula did not work for you.

Option A - TimeValue

The nice thing about your time set up, is that the time is either 10 or 11   characters long from start to finish and if we take all 11 when its really only 10 we again are just snagging a space.  So lets grab the RIGHT time and place this formula in the K column:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT($A1,11))
```

Now if that option does not work for you then we break it down the same way we did for the date.

Option B - Stripping Time

So lets look at patterns to see what we can figure out...that first ":" looks like a great identifier so lets find it the same way we did up for the date.  Let build our time formula in column N:

```
=FIND(":",A1)
```

Let sub that straight into the MID formula to pull the hour

```
=MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)
```

And in Column O we will do the same for minutes and again with a bit of tweaking

```
=MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)+1,2)
```

And since we know that the minutes keep a leading zero for single digit minutes we also know exactly where seconds are going to start.  Lets put this formula in column P:

```
=MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)+4,2)
```

So you might be wondering what to do about the AM/PM  Lets grab that and put that in column Q

```
=RIGHT($A1,2)
```

So now that we have all that information what are we going to do to build the time.  Well first things first is you need to know that Excel like 24 hour clocks.  However it really saves it time as a decimal of a day.  So 12 noon is actually stored as 0.5  or half a day.  Another important thing to know is that the official supported time range for Excel is 00:00 to 23:59.  There is no 24:00.  now having said that 24 as an hour makes VBA crash unless you specifically deal with it in some special code.  You can however get away with supplying 24 as an hour in excel formulas and get away with it sometimes.  ok enough with the time lesson let build this final formula in column R:

```
=TIME(N1+IF(AND(Q1="PM",N1<>"12"),12,IF(AND(Q1="AM",N1="12"),-12,0)),O1,P1)
```

You will note there is an IF formula in there that deal with the AM PM as well as the special case of the 12 hour.  The 12 is in quotes because N1 is a string and I had not converted it to a number.

now for the uglyness of back substituting our formula so it all in one cell.

```
=TIME(MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)+IF(AND(RIGHT($A1,2)="PM",MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)<>"12"),12,IF(AND(RIGHT($A1,2)="AM",MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)="12"),-12,0)),MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)+1,2),MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)+4,2))
```

And yeah that is so easy to read!  I asked if you needed this in one column or two.  Well you have the full formula for the date on its on and the full formula for time on its on.  So if you need them together here is an interesting tid bit of information.  Since Time is stored as decimal days, that means everything to the right of the decimal is time.  It also means that everything to the left (or the integer portion) are days.  So to have date time in one column, you just need to add the two formulas together...or as I refer to it as, the really big ugly equation...or at least one of the many that fall into that category:

```
=DATE(MID($A1,FIND(",",$A1)+2,4),VLOOKUP(LEFT($A1,3),$AA$1:$AB$12,2,0),MID($A1,FIND(",",$A1)-2,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT($A1,11))

or if time value did not work for you

=DATE(MID($A1,FIND(",",$A1)+2,4),VLOOKUP(LEFT($A1,3),$AA$1:$AB$12,2,0),MID($A1,FIND(",",$A1)-2,2))+TIME(MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)+IF(AND(RIGHT($A1,2)="PM",MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)<>"12"),12,IF(AND(RIGHT($A1,2)="AM",MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)-2,2)="12"),-12,0)),MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)+1,2),MID($A1,FIND(":",$A1)+4,2))
```

Now this is just one solution on how to break it down with formulas.  There are other options or route I could have gone at a couple of steps, but it should work for you regardless of what your system settings are.  Here is a screen capture of the results on my system.  note I hid empty columns that were not in use in order to make the image narrower.  Column T has custom formatting of

```
mmm, d, yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM
```

applied to it.

[image: Final product]

### Option 3

*VBA*

I am sure someone will supply at some point.  And look it happened before I could get to that stage!  I don't know why 8)

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, Can you please help me with option 2 ?

Comment: Formula method coming right up.  Takes a bit to do the typing and or testing.  Text to columns is really a nice solution, and oh I see some spplied some VBA.  1 correct prediction from me today 8).

Comment: @NikyRathod So now that option 2 has been further detailed, do you have questions about it?

Answer (score 1):

try `=DATEVALUE("date string")`.

hope this helps

---

here is how it works

[image]

---

if still didn't work, then it has to do with windows date time setting.

Open **Region and Language** setting from Control Panel. Change the **Long Date** format to "MMMM dd,yyyy". Because this is the format your date string is formatted. You have to do this to get DATEVALUE() in excel to work. Now go back to your formula and see if it works.

After that, copy paste the formulas as value. Then you can change back to your preferred long date format again (or just leave it).

[image]

Comment: @NikyRathod, i copy one date from your question and it works fine.

Comment: It won't work if the value in the cell is formatted as text. At least not in Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

As for the VBA solution, you can open VBA editor, add a new module and paste this code:

```
Function STRTODATE(ByVal dcell As Range)
    Dim datecon As Date
    datecon = dcell
    STRTODATE = datecon
End Function
```

then you can use STRTODATE as a formula. Only really helpful, if it's one off. If it's something you'd do regularly on different files, then it can be annoying to paste this code to every workbook.